# Which bigquery version is compatible with google-api-client 1.22.0?

Tags: maven, google-bigquery, java-8

I must use google-api-client `1.22.0` but I couldn't find the bigquery version that works compatible with this google-api-client version. I specified the bigquery dependency as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then i got this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
```

Which version of bigquery should I use? I'll be very glad if you can help.

Comment: Hi @desdemona, can you confirm which version of bigquery you are using?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, I'm using `1.36.0` version of big query.

Comment: Hi @desdemona, since you are using quite old version of google-api-client, I would suggest you to use the BigQuery version `0.6.0`, `0.7.0` or `1.21.0`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it keeps giving the same error, @ShipraSarkar

Comment: Hi @desdemona, can you try by using the latest version of google-api-client i.e. `2.2.0` with the bigquery version `2.21.0`?